# Repeat animation freeze when left mouse button click and hold

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, storyboard

I have made many different storyboard before but for some reason it's the first time i actually noticed that visual bug and wouldn't have noticed if i didn't had complain from higher up about it.

First i have a simple glowing effect on a `Label` nothing complicated running forever on initiated on the `Loaded` event

```
<Label Name="lblFullName" Margin="-10,0,0,0" Foreground="Green" FontWeight="DemiBold" FontSize="14">
    <Label.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect x:Name="myDropEffect" BlurRadius="6" ShadowDepth="0" Color="GreenYellow"  Opacity="0" />
    </Label.Effect>
    <Label.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="myDropEffect"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                     From="0" To="0.8" Duration="0:0:0.5"  
                                     AutoReverse="True"  RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Label.Triggers>
</Label>
```

if i click a button on a window but don't let go the animation keep going on. I have tried different behavior i could try and no matter what the animation continues. But someone found that when you click the window close button in the top right corner of a window but hold down your mouse, every single animation with Forever or those still currently iterating (like 15 sec animation long still animating) they all freeze and if you move the mouse outside the close button before releasing it and then release it all animation on Forever restart from random point withing the animation and not where they were before the freeze.

I created an empty project and i also get this behavior. So on a machine with the application installed and on a dev machine same behavior so I'm perplex. Anyone ever noticed this ? anyone ever found a fix ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when you animate with `CompositionTarget.Rendering` as well.

What you see is a stardard windows behaviour. What is happening is that windows blocks all drawing operations on the window when you hold down the close button. Your animations don't really stop, they just aren't reflected on the window. When you release the button, the elements are drawn exactly the way they would be at that point in time hadn't you frozen the window.

You can test this works with a browser, too. If you hold the close button [in this page](http://jsfiddle.net/BMb65/10/), you'll se the scrolling freezes and then resumes at a later point. So tell you're 'highs' that, except if they know people at Microsoft, that's just Windows. I don't know if other operating systems work the same way.

Maybe someone could explain why windows work that way, but I suppose there's a good reason.

Comment: i was indeed starting to think the refresh was just on hold but everything working behind as expected. Like the way you describe i should tell them what the issue is :). But i am eager to know if someone could explain why this is happening.